# Error 7 while installing Lineageos on Zenfone 2 Z00A

Tags: twrp, lineageos, asus-zenfone-2

I have tried a first install of Lineageos on an Asus Zenfone 2 Z00A.

I have now reformatted all data, done a factory reset and wiped everything  but always getting error 7 in zip install.

I have twrp-3.0.2-0-Z00A.img, lineage 14.1-20170512-nightly-Z00A-signed.zip and open_gapps-z86-7.1-mini-20170513.zip.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Did you try using another version of TWRP?

Comment: No, that's the latest. Should I try and earlier version and if so why?

Comment: Latest doesn't specifically means stable or working. I had problems installing new system on my own ZenFone 2 and downgrading TWRP solved it.